# Deployment FAILS on iOS 14 (Svelte Native, Xcode 12)

Tags: nativescript, svelte-native

This morning I noticed that Xcode was being updated. Once that was done, I was no longer able to deploy my Svelte Native project on the emulator:

Unable to apply changes on device: F863B5B4-A568-4311-9153-9ED22B008275. Error is: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/janos/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F863B5B4-A568-4311-9153-9ED22B008275/data/Applications'. (I have checked and the 'Applications' folder does not exist, but the parent folder does.)

Anyone has any suggestion on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

As funny as it sounds,

`mkdir /Users/janos/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F863B5B4-A568-4311-9153-9ED22B008275/data/Applications`

fixed the issue. As I mentioned in the original question, it was only the Applications folder that did not exist.

Why this happened, and how it's linked to the iOS 14 update, is maybe something we'll never get to know. Anyway, it's working and that's what matters.

Comment: This actually worked for me when running across the same error with a Nativescript app. Thank you.

Comment: Me too with Nativescript! Thanks